# How to quit Skype on 14.04?

Tags: skype

How can I quit Skype, including the background process? Is there a better way than using kill?

Edit: Is there a workaround that kills the process automatically once I close the window?

Comment: Click on the indicator and select "Exit".

Comment: Run this at a terminal:  `pkill skype`

Comment: @Harris "[...] a better way than using kill"

Comment: @Pilot6 why don't you make that an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Running Ubuntu 16.04 and Sykpe 4.3.0.37, I was able to close it via the application itself:

- go to Skype's menu.
- click on menu item: Skype.
- then click on quit.

It exited the application and the background process successfully.